# Post JSON to MVC controller

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I've looked at various questions and answers, however I am only partially successful.

The View is passing this JSON:

```
{JsonInput: [["208-01", "003158"]], JobNumber: "test"}

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/Dash/SavePickups",
   contentType: 'application/json',
   dataType: "json",
   data: JSON.stringify({
       JsonInput: final,
       JobNumber:"test"
       }),
```

The Json String above is sent to the controller at /Dash/SavePickups

```
  [System.Web.Http.Route("Dash/SavePickups/{JsonInput}")]
    public JsonResult SavePickups(object[][] JsonInput)
    {
        var FailResult = new { Success = "False", Message = "Error" };
        var SuccessResult = new { Success = "True", Message = "Pickups Scheduled Successfully." };

       return Json(SuccessResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Only part of the JSON string is passed to the JsonInput.
In Debug I see the JsonInput Object, with the Obj array 208-01 and 003158.

Why isn't JobNumber included, I can see in chrome Network POST its part of the JSON string sent to the controller..

Comment: Your issue is with the data type your trying to deserialize your JSON into. You'd want to make a model such as :  public List<string> slist {get; set;} public string jobno {get; set;}   - And then accept that model as the input to your SavePickups method. This should get all values post'd to your method.

Comment: Check this: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Posting-JSON-Data-to-ASP-NET-MVC-with-Code-Examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuing maccettura's answer - Your issue is with deserializing the JSON into an object. Your given JSON is formatted as 
    { JsonInput : ["1234","5667"], JobNo : "Test" }

Which has one possible data structure of

```
List<string> , String
```

which will not deserialize into a 'sqaure' object such as

```
object [][]
```

I'd recommend making a model for your json that looks like this:

```
 public class SavePickupsModel 
{
     public List<string> JsonInput {get; set;}
     public string JobNo {get; set; }
}
```

Then use that model as input into your method:

```
[HttpPost]
[System.Web.Http.Route("Dash/SavePickups/{JsonInput}")]
public JsonResult SavePickups(SavePickupsModel JsonInput)
{
    var FailResult = new { Success = "False", Message = "Error" };
    var SuccessResult = new { Success = "True", Message = "Pickups Scheduled Successfully." };

   return Json(SuccessResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: [HttpPost] isn't required, but your correct the data type was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by tagging your controller with the `[HttpPost]` attribute

```
[HttpPost]
[System.Web.Http.Route("Dash/SavePickups/{JsonInput}")]
public JsonResult SavePickups(object[][] JsonInput)
{

}
```

I would also point out that your parameter for the action (`object[][] JsonInput`) does not look right to me.  You will likely find that the json does not deserialize to that object type.